# Async functions works weird with Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to understand the mechanism of async functions. I found some code on MDN docs [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), made some modifications and... cannot fully understand how it works.

```js
var resolveAfter2Seconds = function() {
  console.log("starting slow promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(20);
      console.log("slow promise is done");
    }, 6000);
  });
};


var resolveAfter1Second = function() {
  console.log("starting fast promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(10);
      console.log("fast promise is done");
    }, 4000);
  });
};


var sequentialStart = async function() {
  console.log('==SEQUENTIAL START==');

  const slow = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  const fast = await resolveAfter1Second();

  console.log(fast);
  console.log('why?');
  console.log(slow);
}


sequentialStart();
```

For now I know that if we run this code we will immediately receive '==SEQUENTIAL START==' on the console, then "starting slow promise" then we have a Promise with setTimeout which indicates that 'slow promise is done' will appear after 6 seconds and the resolve(20) callback will be kept in api container since execution stack will be empty.JS gives us 'starting fast promise' and after four seconds we get 'fast promise is done' and then immediately 10, 'why?', 20.

I do not understand: what happens in the background exactly - I know that resolve(20) is kept in api container and the rest of the code are executed, then resolve(10) is also kept in api container and when the execution stack is empty they are returned as the results of resolving their Promises.

But:

1. What with the timer? 10,why,20 appears long after their timeout passes - resolve 20 appears on the screen long after 6 seconds.
2. What with order? It seems like they (resolve20 and resolve 10) are ready to be executed and kept in memory until I use them - print them in console in this case? TIME APPEARING and ORDER

I am very determined to understand it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you concerns but: 1) rename the functions to actually match what they do. `resolveAfter1Second()` is actually `resolveAfter4Seconds()` (same for the other). 2) Console output "10, why, 20" comes after all the promises are resolved (that's the trick of `await`, the call _does not return_ until the promise is resolved). 3) A promise is not "resolved" until you actually call `resolve()`, that's what `setTimeout()` does: it _resolves_ the promise after a specified amount of time.

Comment: What do you mean by "API container", and what exactly would be kept in there? This seems to be the source of your confusion.

Comment: Could it be, that you expected the two awaits to *run in parallel*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help clear things up. Async-await is just syntactic sugar, so your `sequentialStart` function is the exact same thing as:

```
var sequentialStart = function() {
  console.log('==SEQUENTIAL START==');

  resolveAfter2Seconds().then(function(slow) {

    resolveAfter1Second().then(function(fast) {

      console.log(fast);
      console.log('why?');
      console.log(slow);
    });
  });
}
```

> I know that resolve(20) is kept in api container and the rest of the code are executed, then resolve(10) is also kept in api container and when the execution stack is empty they are returned as the results of resolving their Promises

That's not what's happening when using async-await, what your code is doing is the following in this specific order:

1. Call `resolveAfter2Seconds()`
2. `await` it to resolve and then assign the resolved value to the constant `slow`
3. Call `resolveAfter1Second()`
4. `await` it to resolve and then assign the resolved value to the constant `fast`
5. Call `console.log(fast)`, **then** `console.log('why?')`, **then**  `console.log(slow)`

It seems like you're expecting the promises to resolve in parallel, as they would if you weren't using async-await but the whole purpose of async-await is to be able to write code with promises as if it was synchronous (i.e. blocking) code without creating a nested mess of `then` callbacks.

Comment: It seems like I totally misunderstood the issue. Thanks for the explanation - especially for the 'steps' and 'syntactic sugar' I think I understand it now :)